# Cómo pasar un valor de Javascript a mi input MIN de html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function pasar() {
  var value = $("#s").val();
  $("#w").val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="s" onchange="pasar();" max="2019-02-01">
<input type="date" id="w" max="2019-02-01" min="">
```

Y lo que quiero es que cuando tenga un valor en mi primer `input`, éste se pase a mi segundo `input`, pero que lo tome en el `min=""`. Pero cuando lo paso me lo muestra como el valor del segundo `input`, pero yo quiero que se muestre como el mínimo de este segundo input, ¿se podrá?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El motivo por el que se está mostrando el valor es porque estás usando el método [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) que asigna el valor; si lo que quieres es cambiar el valor del atributo `min`, tendrás que usar el método [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), que cambia el valor del atributo indicado.

Esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```js
function pasar() {
  var value = $("#s").val();
  $("#w").attr("min", value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="s" onchange="pasar();" max="2019-02-01">
<input type="date" id="w" max="2019-02-01" min="">
```

Comment: excelente alvaro!